# Why DispatcherServlet is not passing the request to RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to understand better Spring Framework and I would like to understand in what way, ServletDispatcher interacts with a Servlet Container, in this case Tomcat, but using programatic approach.

Given the following example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8081; // specify the desired port

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir("."); // Set the base directory (optional)

        // Set up the connector
        Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.setPort(port);
        tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector);

        // Add a servlet context and configure the Spring Boot application
        Context context = tomcat.addContext("", null);

        
        // Create and configure the DispatcherServlet
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        dispatcherServlet.setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class); // Use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext

        // Manually create an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and register the configuration class
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        
        // Set the DispatcherServlet's application context
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        // Register the DispatcherServlet as a servlet
        Tomcat.addServlet(context, "dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/", "dispatcherServlet");

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MyRestController {

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello() {
            return "Hello, Spring Boot!";
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            System.out.println("Running RestController");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.app")
    public static class SpringConfig {
    
        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }
    }
}
```

when I make a http request:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/hello
```

then I notice that Spring Container is loaded but when I execute a http request, DispatcherServlet is not able to pass the request to the RestController. What is missing in my configuration? Because RestController was loaded in the Spring Container.

Logs:

```
Running
Running RestController
Aug 14, 2023 5:21:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Aug 14, 2023 5:21:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Aug 14, 2023 5:21:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
Aug 14, 2023 5:21:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Aug 14, 2023 5:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
17:21:09.549 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
17:21:09.999 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- Completed initialization in 447 ms
17:21:10.021 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound -- No mapping for GET /hello
```

Source code: https://github.com/jabrena/servlet-archaeology/blob/feature/servlet3/myServlet3/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/Main.java

Note: I know that I could use Spring Boot directly, but I trying to learn how Tomcat connect with Spring Framework :)

Comment: I don't think you will learn anything from this but alas as Tomcat doesn't connect with Spring, it only leverages the Servlet API which is also leveraged by Spring, which allows for the integration (with any servlet container). Setting the `contextClass` doesn't do anything. Instead of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` you need to create a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`. Ideally you use the regular Servlet mechanisms to register the servlet and not Tomcat specific ones. Remove the `basePackages` from the `@ComponentScan`, that way it scans from the package it is defined in.

Comment: Not the way you should be using Spring Boot.  More configuration, less code.  Spring Boot turns the model on its head - it has Tomcat or Netty built in.  You just need an executable JAR.

Comment: Exactly, because I am not using Spring Boot in this example, I am using Spring Framework to understand what Spring Boot does for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your comment, I was able to fix it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connector connector = new Connector();
    connector.setPort(8080);

    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector);

    File base = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    Context context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(SpringConfig.class);
    appContext.refresh();

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(appContext);
    Wrapper wrapper = context.createWrapper();
    wrapper.setName("dispatcherServlet");
    wrapper.setServlet(dispatcherServlet);
    context.addChild(wrapper);
    wrapper.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    wrapper.addMapping("/");

    try {
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    @RestController
    public static class MyRestController {

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello() {
            return "Hello world";
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            System.out.println("Running RestController");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.app")
    public static class SpringConfig {

        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }
    }
}
```

It is pretty interesting how Spring Boot help developers minimizing the effort to run a web application with few annotations.

You can see the POC here:
https://github.com/jabrena/servlet-archaeology